# errors moving from ng2.0.0-beta.0 to ng2.0.0-beta.7

Tags: angular

I have an apache cordova typescript project with ng2.0.0-beta.0 package configured and successfully working on startup, see package.json and javascript console output below.

I was attempting to move to the current ng2.0.0-beta.7 package in that project to see if it address an unexpected issue I am experiencing where views are not updating when template referenced class member variables changed, for details see "[cordova app angular 2 member variable update not updating template reference to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449139/cordova-app-angular-2-member-variable-update-not-updating-template-reference-to)".

When I switch to ng2.0.0-beta.7 package everything transpiles fine but ng2 doesn't successfully startup, see package.json and javascript console output below.

I have repro for the ng2.0.0-beta.0 case in master branch of https://github.com/myusrn/acu6withng2 and ng2.0.0-beta.7 case in acu6withng27 topic branch https://github.com/myusrn/acu6withng2/tree/acu6withng27.

Anyone seen this runtime error with ng2.0.0-beta.7 and if so is it due to some step i'm overlooking or perhaps there is a known fix for it?

**ng2.0.0-beta.7 package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.9",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
```

**ng2.0.0-beta.7 runtime javascript console output errors**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: onreadystatechange
angular2-polyfills.js (1569,25)
DEPRECATION WARNING: 'enqueueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use addTask/addRepeatingTask/addMicroTask
angular2-polyfills.js (1152,18)
DEPRECATION WARNING: 'dequeueTask' is no longer supported and will be removed in next major release. Use removeTask/removeRepeatingTask/removeMicroTask
angular2-polyfills.js (1152,18)
reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators
    Error loading http://localhost:4400/app/main.js
angular2-polyfills.js (468,17)
```

**ng2.0.0-beta.0 package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "es6-promise": "3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.9",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
```

**ng2.0.0-beta.0 runtime javascript console output**

```
Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
angular2.dev.js (351,13)
```

**ng2.0.0-beta.0/.7 index.html**

```
<!-- Cordova reference, this is added to your app when it's built. -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
<!--<script src="scripts/appbundle.js"></script>-->
<script src="scripts/index.js"></script>

<!-- 1. Load libraries needed for ng2 -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: i am not using beta 7.0 yet but seems there is nothing changed according to changelog in the beta 7.0 see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta7-2016-02-18

Comment: Could you provide the content of your main HTML file? (scripts, SystemJS configuration, ...) Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Pardeep, thanks for response.  I'd agree that not much has changed from ng2.0.0-beta.6 to .7 but seems like lots of changes going from ng2.0.0.0-beta.0 to .7 if i'm reading that change log page details correctly.

Comment: Hi @Thierry, thanks for response.  I've added index.html <script /> tags details above which is the same for both cases.  More specifics on the contents of index.html, index.ts, app/main.ts and app/app.component.ts can also be found in the github repo I provided reference to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a resolution to this which involved simply adding the following to index.html script tags list and worked with new ng 2.0.0-beta.8 package as well.

```
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
```

Since this detail isn't a part of the current https://angular.io/guide/quickstart I'm not sure if the difference is a problem with my hello world project environment or a detail that needs to get added to quickstart notes on what should go in index.html script tags.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer! Strange but normally the `angular2-polyfills.js` file contains Reflect-metadata...