# Cordova app no showing anything (log says error in ecmascript.js:279)

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, meteor

I followed angular2-meteor tutorial. I tried to debug the app in the simulator and in a smartphone (meteor run android/android-device --verbose). In both cases, the app loads the meteor splash screen. But, after that, only an empty white screen appears.

The only hint I see is within the meteor sun android/android-device logs which state in both cases the following:

```
I20160603-12:17:11.092(2)? D/MeteorWebApp( 2249): Downloaded asset manifest for version: 64e637af5e28546f390d6025d2c3e5661c275905
I20160603-12:17:11.157(2)? I/MeteorWebApp( 2249): Serving asset bundle with version: 64e637af5e28546f390d6025d2c3e5661c275905
I20160603-12:17:13.070(2) (android:http://localhost:12264/packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:279) Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: onreadystatechange
```

I do not know how to continue, how to obtain more information about the error or where is the point where the app failed.

Please, ask me for anything to show. There are so many things that I prefer to post more info as requested to not flooding the post.

Thank you in advance,
Miguel

**Edit:**

These are my dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "health",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-meteor": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-meteor-accounts-ui": "^0.4.3",
    "angular2-meteor-auto-bootstrap": "^0.5.5",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816980/errors-moving-from-ng2-0-0-beta-0-to-ng2-0-0-beta-7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816980/errors-moving-from-ng2-0-0-beta-0-to-ng2-0-0-beta-7)

Comment: Jesper, what should I look there?? (I have added my dependencies.)

Comment: try to run (since you have a meteor project) `meteor npm install --save reflect-metadata`

Comment: I am using angular2-meteor. It needs version 0.1.2 I am using that version instead of 0.1.3 which is the one that npm will install. Check dependencies of angular2-meteor here: https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Is it possible to tell to use 0.1.3 version instead of 0.1.2 to resolve the dependencies, somehow??

Comment: maybe you can try to manually adjust the version of this dependency to 0.1.3 in the package.json file of the angular2-meteor package in your node_modules folder

Comment: I tried but it says that is incompatible: `npm ERR! peerinvalid The package reflect-metadata@0.1.3 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer angular2-meteor@0.5.5 wants reflect-metadata@0.1.2
`